# QuickAction anchor after keyboard hidden

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a `Button` at the bottom of my `Activity`.
Upon pressing the Button, an `AlertDialog` with an `EditText` pops up.
After clicking OK, the `AlertDialog` dismisses, and I want to show a [`QuickAction`](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) anchored to the `Button`.
However, when soft-keyboard appears, all of my `View`s are moved upward, and the `QuickAction` would anchored the `Button` at the center of the `Activity`. Then after a while when soft-keyboard dismiosses, all `View`s are moved to the original location, but the `QuickAction` is still floating at the center, not anchored the `Button`.

Is there any solution to this soft-keyboard issue?
(PS: I don't want the soft-keyboard to overlay my `Activity` so that user cannot see the `EditText`. I want the `EditText` to be visible.)

Answer (score 0):

you should update `QuickAction`'s location after soft-keyboard disappears.
try take a look at its source code about determining the location of `QuickAction` (in the `public synchronized void show (View anchor) {...}`). 

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) helps to detect keyboard closing.